# How can I download a iOS Shortcuts file to my Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, shortcut

I have created a iOS shortcuts (Workflow) on a iPad. Finally, I would like to save and send a backup to Mac. This has been really easy in the past. Unfortunately it is no longer possible to share any Shortcuts via eMail, ftp client or other non iCloud services. It looks like Apple locked down Shortcuts to iCloud. Users are forced to use iCloud. Anyway, when I click the iCloud 'Get Shortcut' link it won't download the workflow://shortcuts file.

How can I download a iOS shortcut to my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a shortcut you have on your iOS device to a `.shortcut` file using this shortcut: [Save .shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/ffd11e2a5b8743039b7727a184b3c333). This works with shortcuts you’ve created or imported from iCloud.

Run the shortcut to be prompted to choose a shortcut from your list of shortcuts, then the Quick Look action opens the shortcut as a file, and you can share the file using the Share button in the top-right to Save to Files, AirDrop or elsewhere.

Unfortunately it’s no longer possible to import .shortcut files back into the Shortcuts app by opening them on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for in-depth explanation. It worked like a charm! This is exactly I was looking for. Due to the lack to re-import .shortcut files back from macOS to iOS clients it's kind of useless. To deploy shortcuts files you have to use iCloud shared link. I would prefer to share .shortcut files directly via email or WebServer.